# In RShiny using renderPrint/renderText to show error when expected files are missing in downloadHandler

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I am using a downloadHandler in a shiny app which let's me download 4 reactive dataframes that has been created. I want to include a functionality if either one of the dataframes has not been created then that will be printed in renderPrint/renderText saying one of the dataframes is missing. A minimal example from the server code is given below but it does not work the way I want it to.

```
output$dl <-
      if((df1()!= '') || (df2()!='') || (df3()!= '') || (df4()!= '') ){
      downloadHandler(
      filename = "New_Data.xlsx",
      content = function(file){
        write_xlsx(list("S1" = df1(), "S2" = df2(), "S3" = df3(), "S4" = df4()), path = file)
      }else{
output$dl_error <- renderPrint({'One of the dataframes is missing'})
}
      )
```

or something like this

```
    data_list <- reactive({
      list("S1" = df1(),
           "S2" = df2(),
           "S3" = df3(),
           "S4" = df4())
    })
    output$dl <- reactive({
       if(length(data_list()==4)){
         downloadHandler(
           filename = "New_Data.xlsx",
           content = function(file){
             write_xlsx(data_list(), path = file)
           }
         )
       }else{
         output$dl_error <- renderPrint({'One of the dataframes is missing'})
       }
    })
```

It will be great if someone can help me out with this. Also, it would be better if the error message in the renderPrint/renderText shows which dataframe is missing.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I would rather disable the download button until the four df are available.

Comment: How to disable the download button like you are proposing as that would also solve my problem and if possible alongwith a message when user clicks on disabled download button telling the user that files are not available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in my comment, you could disable the button. You can use the **shinyjs** package to do that easily. Another option is to hide the download button with a `conditionalPanel`. Here is a third option. I hide the download button with a `conditionalPanel` and instead I display a "fake" download button. When the dataframe is available, the fake data button is hidden and the true download button becomes visible. If the user clicks on the fake download button, he is told that the dataframe is not available with an alert.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)
library(writexl)

ui <- fluidPage(
 useShinyalert(),
 br(),
 conditionalPanel(
   condition = "!output.ok",
   actionButton("fake", "Download", icon = icon("save"))
 ),
 conditionalPanel(
   condition = "output.ok",
   style = "display: none;",
   downloadButton("dwnld", "Download", icon = icon("save"))
 ),
 br(),
 actionButton("databtn", "Generate dataframe")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input[["fake"]], {
    shinyalert(
      title = "Error!",
      text = "The dataframe is not ready yet",
      type = "error"
    )
  })
  
  df <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input[["databtn"]], {
    df(iris)
  })
  
  output[["ok"]] <- reactive({
    !is.null(df())
  })
  outputOptions(output, "ok", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  
  output[["dwnld"]] <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "iris.xlsx",
    content = function(file){
      write_xlsx(list(iris = df()), path = file)     
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: This has helped me solve my problem. Thank you for your help!